# How do you subdivide an array into n number of subarrays, such that the sum of each subarray is as equal as possible?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

So an example of the question is as follows:

Let's say we want to subdivide `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` into `3` sub-arrays.

While I imagine there are many correct answers one of them would be, `[10, 8], [9, 7, 2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. The reason being that here the sum of the sub arrays is, `18, 18, 19`, meaning they are as close to equal as they can possibly be.

Is there an algorithm that can consistently return such an answer given any starting array and any number of sub-arrays to divide into? (Assuming that: length of the starting array > number of sub-arrays)

(PS If you want to show your logic in code I feel the most comfortable with python.)

Comment: Does it need to be efficient? You can just try all possibilities, with some optimizations to quickly break out of suboptimal attempts.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning

Comment: @IVlad It can be a little bit more complicated than that because you need to make sure that if there are multiple solutions, that you choose the right numbers according to the solution. So given the above answer [10, 8], [9, 7, 2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6] || this is also a valid answer 3 4 1 10 | 5 6 7 | 2 8 9, so you need to choose from all the options the correct subsets which correspond to the correct answer to return it.

Comment: A subarray is a contiguous part of an array. This is not what you want. But unsure what is the correct word, maybe subsequence.

Comment: @AriFrid  Is the array always sorted ?